# Ordering prints from iPhoto and having them shipped to a different country?

Tags: photos.app, graphics, accounts

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to order prints through iPhoto, and have the prints shipped to a different country than the one you chose when you setup your print account.

In the account setup page, you can only choose to setup new shipping addresses which are in the same country as the account you're using (I think).

What I would like to do is to order some prints through my Canadian iPhoto account (and make the payment with a Canadian credit card), and have them shipped to an address in Japan as a gift.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this somehow?

Comment: I know this post is from a while ago, but I am having the same problem, I would like to ship prints to the US and pay for them with my UK card. I have managed to change the shipping address to US but this automatically changes the billing address to require a US one, I cannot pay with my UK account. Did you manage to make the billing address and shipping address different? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a "solution" (more like a workaround) which worked for us. Thought I'd post it, in case someone else is in the same situation.

- Go to iTunes and change the address of your Apple account and the credit card to the country you want to order the pictures to (I think you can also do this online from Apple's website)
- Restart iPhoto; you should now be able to ship prints to another country
- When you're done, switch back to the country where you're living

It's rather inconvenient, but it works.